# How to shear a ellipse

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

[image]

I am working on a scientiic illustration and I need your help. :)

I want to make an ellipse with left end at (0, 0 , 0) and the right end at (1, 1, 1) where the middle point is at (0.5, 0.5, 0.5). All I have to do is to shear the ellipse shown in the figure in such a way that right end should be at (1,1,1) and the middle point at (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) and left end remain at zero.

How to shear it....?

[image]

I tried propotional editing by moving the right end vertice point but it gives non symmetrical ellipse.

Comment: have you tried the Shear tool (ctrl alt shift S), doesn't it give a good result? also, Mesh Deform modifier could help you

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways to do it: *Shear* tool or *Mesh Deform* modifier

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Matrices and Scripting**

Since it is for a *"scientific visualization"* I thought some maths and scripting wouldn't go astray.

**[`Matrix.Shear(plane, size, factor)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix.Shear)**

For the example here the plane chosen is XY, The normal of the XY plane is the Z axis.  For this case, consider the two values of factor as the x and y component that make up the 2D shearing vector. `(1, 1)` (Top ortho view)

The unit diameter sphere is sitting on its base, the z axis passes thru both poles.  The Each ring of latitude has been "*sheared*" maintaining a constant z value  from `(0, 0, 1)` to  `(1, 1, h)`  Where `h = 1` is the "height" (diameter) of the sphere.

[image]
*Before and after shear*

Test script. Adds a UV sphere at origin. Scales mesh to diameter one, and translates such that origin is on south pole.

Applies the XY plane shearing matrix along 1, 1.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

# Add a diameter one sphere sitting on its base.

context = bpy.context
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(location=(0, 0, 0))
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
T = Matrix.Translation((0, 0, 1))

Sc = 0.5 * Matrix.Identity(4)
me.transform(T * Sc)

#  Shearing 

Sh = Matrix.Shear('XY', 4, (1, 1))

me.transform(Sh)
```

[image]

Oops on re reading question see you wanted origin at (0.5, 0.5, 0.5), wont apply transform to me, will leave at origin and translate object.

```
Sh = Matrix.Shear('XY', 4, (1, 1))
Sc = 0.5 * Matrix.Identity(4)
me.transform(Sh * Sc)

ob.matrix_world.translation = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>**SPACE**</kbd> type in "shear", click the search result and shear. Next time just use the hotkey given next to it.

Comment: wooohooo. It worked. Thankyou so much. It is exactly what I wanted. :)